# If $A(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is "the area function," why are we allowed to choose different values for $a$?

Tags: calculus

From my textbook I have obtained this definition.

$$A(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\mathrm dt$$

where $A(x)$ is the area function of $f(t)$, $a$ is a constant, and $x$ is a variable.

If $a = 0$ then according to the textbook this should be true: $$A(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt.$$

What if now $a = 5$? According to the textbook it would still be $$A(x) = \int_5^x f(t)\mathrm dt.$$

How is that the area from $0$ to $x$ is equal to the area from $5$ to $x$ for the same graph? Something is not right here.

Comment: I've tried improving your title to something more informative. Perhaps this isn't the best way of putting it, but you could try for something better than what you had to start with.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't the same. In general, you get different area functions for different choices of $a$. For this reason a better notation would be $A_a(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, but this clutters things up.